# Problem with adding to list inside a loop in java

Tags: java

I wrote a code to check if an array is not in a list, then it should add it to another list. I used a linked list for this. But my problem is the program always add multiple copies of the current array and remove what's inside in the list before: My code is as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Trial{

    public static void main(final String[] args){

        final List<int[]> G = new LinkedList<int[]>();
        final List<int[]> New = new LinkedList<int[]>();

        final int[] f = new int[2];

        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
                f[0] = i;
                f[1] = j;
                // System.out.println("f is "+Arrays.toString(f));
                if(!(G.contains(f))){
                    System.out.println("current f is " + Arrays.toString(f));
                    // I print here in order to see what is f
                    New.add(f);
                    System.out.println("content of the list New");
                    // I print the list New to see its contents
                    for(int k = 0; k < New.size(); k++){
                        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(New.get(k)));
                    }
                    System.out.println("finished printing the list New");
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

And this is the result I got after running:

```
current f is [0, 0]
content of the list New
[0, 0]
finished printing the list New
current f is [0, 1]
content of the list New
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
finished printing the list New
current f is [1, 0]
content of the list New
[1, 0]
[1, 0]
[1, 0]
finished printing the list New
current f is [1, 1]
content of the list New
[1, 1]
[1, 1]
[1, 1]
[1, 1]
finished printing the list New
```

Please help!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't add multiple copies, it allways add f as a new list item after first iteration you have f then f,f then f,f,f then f,f,f,f in your list. And you are allways modifing your only array f so all elements conatin the same two numbers

You should change:

```
for(int j=0; j<2; j++){
f[0] = i;
```

to

```
for(int j=0; j<2; j++){
f = new int [2];
f[0] = i;
```

I don't understand your condition

```
if(!(G.contains(f))){
```

f is never in the G because you never put it there, so no possible chance it could get there

Comment: Yeah it works. Yeah the condition if(!(G.contains(f)))
is really doing nothing here, I removed some parts of the code just to clarify this problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

if I'm not mistaken this is a classical error in Java

your not creating new objects !!! so your always adding and modifying the same one ego in the end your list contains one 1 object over and over again.

wha tyou want is to move

```
int [] f = new int [2];
```

into your for loop

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are new to java.
And I also assume that this is a sample program, or some sort of an exercise.

You want to check whether a list contains an array. You are using `list.contains` which is correct.

The problem is how you are constructing the array.

In the following snippet

```
   int [] f = new int [2]; 

   for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
   { 
      for(int j=0; j<2; j++)
      { 
         f[0] = i; 
         f[1] = j;
         list.add(f);
      }
  }
```

there is only one array you are constructing, outside the `for` loop.
You are actually adding to the same array again and again.
And adding this array again and again to the list. The list will contain 4 elements, but all 4 will refer to the same array.

If you want the list to contain different elements, then you have to create them first:

```
for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
       { 
          for(int j=0; j<2; j++)
          { 
             int [] f = new int [2]; //<-- new array everytime
             f[0] = i; 
             f[1] = j;
             list.add(f);
          }
      }
```

Coming to your contains check:

Your check will always be false, because the list `G` will always be empty (from the code you have given) you are not adding anything to it.

Since `G.contains...` check will always be `false` (`G` contains nothing), all the elements will be added to `New`.

If you want to have some sample code to understand contains, you might want to add something to `G` first.

```
       for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
       {  
             int [] f = new int [2]; //<-- new array everytime
             f[0] = i; 
             f[1] = i;
             G.add(f);
       }

     //G will now contain [0,0] and [1,1]

       for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
       { 
          for(int j=0; j<2; j++)
          { 
             int [] f = new int [2]; //<-- new array everytime
             f[0] = i; 
             f[1] = j;
             if(!G.contains(f))
             {
                New.add(f); //Will add only [0,1] and [1,0]
             }
          }
      }
```

Final notes: In java, it is conventional to have lowercase variable names. 
Perhaps not very importane for a sample program, but try to have meaningful variable names. Names like `f` and `G` don't convey much.